# Deploying code from SVN to production

Tags: svn, deployment, packaging

My coworker and I are debating how to deploy code.
Currently we run rsync which copies code from our SVN to all production servers.

All fine and dandy, but I think we also need a way to deploy a package containing just the files I need. I don't want to sync my entire code base when I want patch 1 or 2 php files. He disagrees with the idea of having packages, which would contain just the code I need, instead of the entire SVN.

Please tell me I'm not crazy for wanting packages!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a program like Jenkins. Jenkins will identify if a code has changed on SVN, automatically make the build from the code (or just copy the code eg. ASP) and make the deploy to your desire environment (production, homolog, develop).

Dig on web for Continuous Integration.

Answer (score 0):

For a simple architecture/project you could use an SVN client for each step.

DEV->QA->PROD.

E.g.
DEV commits 2 files

QA svn update just those 2.

If all works update in the PROD too.

Comment: But what If I commit, then realize there is a problem? Meanwhile, I need to fix a bug in some other code? I would want the option to patch 1 or 2 files. Isn't that reasonable?

Comment: You can 'svn revert' specific files to specific releases